# What is this called? A tube flange bearing threaded for threaded pushrod

Tags: replacement-parts, part-identification

How should I describe this part which looks like a threaded flange so that I can research replacements? It is the gold piece in the middle of each photo. It is used to create a bed raiser in the FLSUN Cube 3D printer.

[image]

[image]
[image]

It gets attached to a motor using a flexible bearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[This answer](/a/10597/) already describes the name of the "golden" component you are after, this answer expands upon that answer to note that there are various nuts with different thread sizes that look virtually the same, it would be a pity to order the incorrect one.*

---

Note that this trapezoidal lead screw nut is made from brass (e.i. in your image, but these nuts are also available in POM/Delrin) and needs to have exactly the same screw threads as your lead screw has. A much used lead screw is using the following designation `Tr8x8(p2)` ( for a full description of what that means look into [this answer (Anet A8 lead screw threads)](/a/5668/)). Do note that there are many lead screw nut sizes, buying the wrong one will not fit the current lead screw.

[image: Example of various lead size lead screw nuts]

From the image you supplied it looks as if that is the same lead screw as used in the linked answer of the Anet A8 lead screw. To verify this, you could measure how much the nut advances on a full rotation of the nut, if it is 8 mm, buy the `Tr8x8(p2)` if e.g. 4 mm, buy the `Tr8x4(p2)`. Note that if you are going to buy a new nut, you could opt for a nut that has no backlash, **BUT**, be sure that it would fit the acrylic hole and you have enough space as its height is larger, or be prepared to modify the acrylic part or reconstruct a new one (it wouldn't be a bad idea to do that anyways, acrylic is known for cracking under applying force such as screws and nuts). Note that an anti backlash nut must be used as depicted below.

[image: image of an anti backlash lead screw nut]

Comment: There is also ACME thread, which is visually very similar.

Comment: ACME thread does look similar, but the channels have a different profile, and they are not crafted with the same precision.

Comment: The trapezoidal metric thread form is similar to the ACME thread form, except the thread angle is 30° (29° for ACME). This difference is so small to notice by eye.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, it's just called a **lead screw nut** or **lead nut**. The flange and holes for attaching it to a surface are inherent in its role in letting the lead screw move something.